# Keyboard shortcut app crashes with segmentation fault [io.elementary.shortcut-overlay]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, crash, odin

Anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

FYI:

- on new account it works
- tried uninstall/install, didn't help
- I don't have any clue at which moment it stopped working, since I don't use it often

```
arnis@kerrigan:~$ io.elementary.shortcut-overlay

** (io.elementary.shortcut-overlay:18707): CRITICAL **: 18:50:03.480: gee_abstract_collection_get_size: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

** (io.elementary.shortcut-overlay:18707): CRITICAL **: 18:50:03.481: gee_abstract_collection_add: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

(io.elementary.shortcut-overlay:18707): GLib-CRITICAL **: 18:50:03.482: g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
Segmentation fault
arnis@kerrigan:~$
```

journalctl log:

```
okt 29 18:33:54 kerrigan kernel: io.elementary.s[17466]: segfault at 0 ip 000055e8af2e0f73 sp 00007ffd67d69a20 error 4 in io.elementary.shortcut-overlay[55e8af2df000+4000]
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens if shortcut key is removed.

Apparently it's a bug that have been fixed in [version 1.2.1](https://github.com/elementary/shortcut-overlay/releases/tag/1.2.1)